# Creating indicator variable for an event taking place within a date range between two dataframes in R

Tags: r, date

I would like to create an indicator variable that indicates if one or more heatwaves occurred within the 7 days prior to an event. I have two data frames. One that contains the event information (including date, and other variables). The second contains climate information (including heatwave date, and a binary heat wave variable). I would like to create the indicator in the event data. This is is what the data looks like:

```
Event Data 
Event    Date         Other_Vars..  
 1       05-01-2016        .
 0       06-12-2016        .
 1       07-15-2016        .
 
 Climate Data
Heatwave      Date       
   1         07-06-2016
   0         07-07-2016
   1         07-08-2016
   0         07-09-2016
   0         07-10-2016
   1         07-11-2016
```

What I would like the end result to look like:

```
Event Data
 Event    Date         Other_Vars..   Indicator
 1       05-01-2016        .           0
 0       06-12-2016        .           0
 1       07-15-2016        .           1
```

The first event did not have a corresponding heatwave within the prior 7 days so the indicator is 0. For the second event there were two heatwaves that occurred within the prior 7 days so the indicator is 1.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

You can try this

```
library(dplyr)

prep <- . %>% mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%m-%d-%Y"))

prep(df_event) %>% 
  mutate(Date7 = Date - 7L) %>% 
  left_join(prep(df_climate), by = c("Date7" = "Date")) %>% 
  mutate(Indicator = as.integer(!is.na(Heatwave) & Heatwave == 1), Date7 = NULL, Heatwave = NULL)
```

Output

```
  Event       Date Other_Vars.. Indicator
1     1 2016-05-01            .         0
2     0 2016-06-12            .         0
3     1 2016-07-15            .         1
```

Data

```
> dput(df_event)
structure(list(Event = c(1L, 0L, 1L), Date = c("05-01-2016", 
"06-12-2016", "07-15-2016"), Other_Vars.. = c(".", ".", ".")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

> dput(df_climate)
structure(list(Heatwave = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Date = c("07-06-2016", 
"07-07-2016", "07-08-2016", "07-09-2016", "07-10-2016", "07-11-2016"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! When I run the code provided it creates an Indicator variable where every observation is 1 except for when the Heatwave variable = NA. When I filter out all the NAs the Indicator variable then has a value of 1 for every observation. Do you have an idea why that is happening? Thanks!